# Is "emery thread" a thing?

Tags: wood, cutting

I read an at least partially true story about a man who escapes prison by sawing through iron bars using 'emery thread'. A google search for such returns only stories about dangerous kite-fighting in India.

Is there such a thing? I imagine it would be very useful for sawing off branches close to the trunk or tree stumps close to the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the standpoint of commercially available products, there are abrasive cord and tape variants:

[abrasive cord](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000REGVES)

Some of the applications for the smaller diameters appear geared toward cleaning threads in rusty bolts, although for the purpose referenced in the original post, patience and elbow grease should result in severing most items.

[image: abrasive cording]

Answer (score 1):

It's more commonly known as a [wire saw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_saw).

Wood cutting variants are sold as a survival tool for sawing off branches.

Comment: I've never tried one of the survival wire saws with the two finger rings that are worthwhile.  I now carry a variation that is basically a manual chainsaw - a length attached to two handles.  There are variations that can be thrown up trees for pruning.  It's work, but I've cut four inch branches.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. It would take a long time depending on the quality of the abrasive and the hardness of the bars.